# Loop terminates after fourth iteration

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, c++14

This is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long
int main()
{
    ll int a;cin>>a;
    ll int i=1;
    ll int arr[i];
    while(a)
    {
        arr[i-1]=a%10;
        a/=10;
        i++;
        cout<<a<<" ";
    }
    i--;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<i<<endl;
}
```

And I get the output as

```
>12345 1234 123 0 
>4
```

for input:

```
123456
```

The loop terminates after fourth iteration, even when the while condition is not satisfied. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: arr is a bit small

Comment: arr size is 1 btw

Comment: What is the objective of this program?

Comment: Are you sure this code can be compiled? The size of array is supposed to be fixed at compile time. "arr[i-1]=a%10;" will certainly cause out of range problem.

Comment: maybe simply in every loop print values in all variables - you will see how code works. OR learn how to use debugger.

Comment: @theelee it's not valid C++ although [a few C++ compilers like GCC do accept it as extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)

Answer (score -2):

First of all given code snipped shall not compile due to below statement

`ll int arr[i];`

Change i to some constant value as shown below

`ll int arr[1];`

Then it shall iterate loop 6 times and shall give below result

**Input :** 123456

**Output :**

12345 1234 123 12 1 0

6

Comment: arr[1] will crash the program here due to access violation since arr size is 1